# about checking isomorphism (definition and example)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Definition: Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. We say $V$ is isomorphic to $W$ if there exists a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ that is invertible. Such a linear transformation is an isomorphism from V onto W.

I am given an example:

> Define $T:F^2 \rightarrow P_1(F)$ by $T(a_1,a_2)=a_1+a_2*x$. $T$ is an isomorphism; so $F^2$ is isomorphic to $P_1(F)$.

To check isomorphism, is that like: let $\beta$ be a basis for $F^2$ and $\gamma$ a basis for $P_1$. Then define $U: P_1 \rightarrow F^2$. As long as $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$*$[U]^{\beta}_{\gamma}$=$I_W$ and $[U]^{\beta}_{\gamma}$*$[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$=$I_V$, we can claim isomorphism?

Comment: Any invertible function is onto: if $f\colon X\to Y$ is invertible, and $g$ is the inverse, then for any $y\in Y$, $f(g(y))=y$, so $y$ is in the image.

Comment: If there's $w$ in $W$ with no $v$ in $V$ satisfying $T(v)=w$, then $T^{-1}(w)$ doesn't exist. So, if $T$ isn't onto, it's not invertible.